# How to use array in jest cli option --testPathIgnorePatterns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I need to use the option `--testPathIgnorePatterns` with more than one folder, one in src and the other in node_modules. How to use this pattern? I didn't find any example.

I can't use the array in the package.json, only as bash option

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon the same issue. You can provide one or more of the same arguments as such:

```sh
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns ./src/path --testPathIgnorePatterns ./node_modules/path
```

In the package script you use it the same way:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --testPathIgnorePatterns ./src/path --testPathIgnorePatterns ./node_modules/path"
}
```

From [their documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathignorepatternsregexarray) you should be able to use the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=\\(/src/path/ /node_modules/path/\\)"
}
```

But I could never get it to work.